# How to securely install web applications on untrusted hosts?

Tags: webserver, trust

In principle, storing data securely on an untrusted server seems to be easy. Just use a strong enough client side encryption.

But how to deal with web applications? For example a forum software like https://github.com/discourse/discourse, a Django app, or something like that?

Are there any concepts to run such software securely on untrusted hosts? In particular, I am interested in running a private forum software on a potentially unsecure host.

Comment: Just don´t. You can´t roll out your encryption stuff on each webbrowser in this world, so the only place left is the server. If it isn´t the server, it´s nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

Securely storing web application on untrusted server is **not possible**. Even if you would encrypt database on the server, you could not use server-side commands. Everything would have to be processed on the client (who has private key or password), including login, so this method is insecure as well.